# Quartz (2 jobFactory)how to configure integration in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, quartz-2d

- Using Quartz 2.2.2
- Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE
- How to my configuration quartz?, use only **Anotation all**
- Start my system ok
- The problem consist 2 jobFactory for system

```js
@Configuration(value = "springConfigContext")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ApplicationScoped
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com", })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:springBeans.xml" })
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:/META-INF/my_file_properties.properties") })
public class SpringConfigContext extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext implements BeanFactory{
 @Bean
 public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean methodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean(){
  //my code
 }
 @Bean
 public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean simpleTriggerFactoryBean(){
  //my code
 }
 @Bean
 public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
  //my code
 }
 @Bean
 public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean() throws ParseException{
  //my code
 }
 @Bean(name = "springQuartzScheduler")
 public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws Exception{
     SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
  CronTrigger trigger = cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject();
  scheduler.setTriggers(simpleTriggerFactoryBean().getObject(), trigger);
  Properties propertie = new Properties();
  propertie.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "3");
  propertie.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "3");
  scheduler.setQuartzProperties(propertie);
  scheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
  scheduler.setApplicationContext(this);
  scheduler.start();
  return scheduler;
 }
}
```

the first build for method public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() 
the second build for other Class, Spring i'm think!

my config properties for Quartz are:

```js
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=schedulerFactoryBean
org.quartz.scheduler.jobFactory.class=org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5 
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
```

I'm try to use same name of the bean "springQuartzScheduler" or schedulerFactoryBean but does't work.

See the image of the problem
[image: Imagem 2 factory Quartz]

How parameterize to use only one factory?

Answer (score 1):

My problem found and **Solved**, when I'm remove one artifact maven call javamelody, **net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter** that was used for monitoring my project.war in production. if you have one other artifact same proposition, **should be responsible for creating a new instance of new factory Quartz**

So if you have a similar problem **2 JobFactory Bean**, assess their artifacts they possibly are responsible for generating more than one instance the factory Quartz, as Quartz does not has factory bean singleton for VM, it's creates a new factory when it is invoked, with same properties of the file quartiz.properties, but when use in other context.

how found problem? put logback in mode log trace, this way you will see invoked factory Quartz, removes the indexed or adjust so that they use the same factory